# Use Swing Timer in Java to Draw Different Shapes at Intervals

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, timer

I have to write a project that generates a randomly-sized, filled-in shape (triangle, pentagon, or hexagon) every three seconds in a java gui. It also has to allow the user to choose a color from a jlist. The color of the shapes will be black until the user chooses one from the list, and then the color of the shapes will be the chosen color. I'm not exactly sure where or how to implement a timer in my code. I'm also not sure where I would add the code to draw the shapes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public enum MyColor {
            BLUE("Blue"), RED("Red"), GREEN("Green"), ORANGE("Orange"), MAGENTA("Magenta");

    private String color;

    private MyColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMyColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getMyColor();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorPane extends JPanel{

    private MyColor myColor;

    public void setMyColor(MyColor myColor) {
        this.myColor = myColor;
        repaint();
    }

    public MyColor getMyColor() {
        return myColor;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(700, 700);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        MyColor myColor = getMyColor();
        g2.fillRect(20,20,300,300);

        if(myColor == null) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        switch (myColor) {
            case BLUE:
                g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case RED:
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case GREEN:
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case ORANGE:
                g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                break;
            case MAGENTA:
                g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class MainPane2 extends JPanel{

    private JList<MyColor> colorList;
    private ColorPane colorPane;

    public MainPane2() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        DefaultListModel<MyColor> dlm = new DefaultListModel<MyColor>();
        dlm.addElement(MyColor.BLUE);
        dlm.addElement(MyColor.RED);
        dlm.addElement(MyColor.GREEN);
        dlm.addElement(MyColor.ORANGE);
        dlm.addElement(MyColor.MAGENTA);

        colorPane = new ColorPane();

        colorList = new JList<MyColor>(dlm);
        colorList.setVisibleRowCount(2);
        colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(colorList);
        colorList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                MyColor myColor = colorList.getSelectedValue();
                colorPane.setMyColor(myColor);
            } 

        });
        add(colorPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Driver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver2();
    }

    public Driver2() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Random Shapes");
                frame.add(new MainPane2());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about "responsibility".  Would it be `ColorPane` or `MainPane2` responsibility to manage the `Timer`? What impacts would occur if one was chosen over the other?  Conceptually, you need a Swing `Timer` which repeats every 3 seconds and which will repaint `ColorPane`. In of itself a simple problem with a simple solution, what **you** need to decide is where the `Timer` would best be suited to achieve your goal

Comment: Is using a `Timer` a requirement or is just drawing a new shape every three seconds the requirement? There are other ways to draw things intermittently than with just a `Timer`.